# Access dispatchedProps actions in mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I need to call an action in `mapStateToProps`, how can I have it?

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  someAction,
};
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    globalParameters: 'some code goes here ...',
    relatedDropDownValue: someAction({SOME_TYPE}),
  });
```

The real code is more complicated but I simplified it.
I need to call `someAction` but I don't know how to get it in `mapStateToProps`. Is it possible at all?

Comment: IMHO it's not possible. `mapStateToProps` is intended for slicing store `state` and giving it to component. What are you trying to achieve by doing so?

Comment: Also, action doesn't return values, you need to call this action in CDM and then "select" it from store using mapStateToProps

Comment: Why don't you call the Action right inside the component? `useEffect(() => {}, [])` or `compounentDidMount`

Comment: In fact, I have to call a function in mapStateToProps that needs a ready-to-dispatch action as parameter to call it in some conditions. @PrathapReddy

Comment: @Roy.B and SirwanAfifi
I need to check state and see if some data is not available, fetch them from API. This is why I need to do that. And believe me, I have no choice to call the action in useEffect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` is not the place to dispatch actions, rather just to map some state from redux store to the props in your component.

The logic should be refactored as such that the component can decide on what action to dispatch (i.e. `useEffect`).

So the component must have enough data from the store, to decide what parameters should be given to the action to dispatch.

If there is a need to fetch data, the component should decide to do that, just keep in mind that whatever you wanted to do in the `mapStateToProps`, should be moved into the component and be dealt with.